# Can temperature have an impact on ionization potential of atoms?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, atomic-physics, plasma-physics

The ionization potential depends on the ionization state and lately it has been known to depend in density  through a process known as Ionization Potential Depression. I've been asking if the temperature could have a similar effect?

Comment: Only in that the other particles which could collide with the neutral atom resulting in ionization would have a higher kinetic energy, i.e., temperature is related to the mean, random kinetic energy in the particle species rest frame.  So at high temperatures, the gas particles are more likely to cause ionization if they collide with each other.  Once ionized, the temperature would also matter in the recombination rate, since higher kinetic energy electrons are less likely to be captured by nuclei.  Note all of this is for non-relativistic energies.